# Oracle SQL Group by self made column?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

im having this Statement:

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN teile LIKE 'S%' THEN
           'vent'
          ELSE
           teile
       END AS teile,
       SUM(amount) 
.
 GROUP BY bereich, teile
```

The result is something like this

```
D1    10070
ER    6278
MO    6278
vent  20140
vent  20140
vent  20140
```

Now i want to summarize the amount of every "vent" and group it another time to "vent" to look like this :

```
D1   10070     
ER   6278     
MO   6278
vent 60420
```

tried it several times with different things but i just cant get it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `CASE` expression from the `SELECT` clause in your `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN teile LIKE 'S%' THEN
           'vent'
          ELSE
           teile
       END AS teile,
       SUM(amount) 
...
 GROUP BY 
       CASE
          WHEN teile LIKE 'S%' THEN
           'vent'
          ELSE
           teile
       END;
```

Comment: tried this before, but didnt work out - after looking in your statement more precisely it worked out - thx!

Answer (score 4):

Another way in addition:

```
SELECT teile, SUM(amount) AS total_amt FROM
(
 SELECT (CASE WHEN teile LIKE 'S%' THEN 'vent' ELSE teile END) AS teile
       , amount 
FROM your_table
)
GROUP BY teile
/
```

Comment: +1: I prefer this method as it follows the "Don't Repeat Yourself" principle.